# Visible cart in the header when it's empty

Tags: wordpress, header, woocommerce, cart, visible

Is it possible to make the cart visible when it's empty in the header? 
And is it possible to make the cart a call to action button in the header?

The site is [vinesso.dk](http://vinesso.dk)

Tank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your cart "logo" get's set to display: none when the cart is empty. 
simply override it in your templates custom css file or directly in the style.css

```
.pex-woo-cart-btn {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much! Do you know how to make the cart a call to action so when you click the cart you go to the checkout page?

Comment: do you have access to the javascript in the template?